# intelij react-native error : Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

Tags: react-native

Please fix the error.

1. java version "14.0.2"
2. Gradle 6.5.1

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:35061) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 449ms

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081